# How to open the lookup form using javascript in crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I create a new button in ribbon If i click that button ,i need to open the **"Send Direct mail"** look up form.**How to open the following lookup form using javascript in crm 2011 when the button is clicked**.

[image]

Comment: please specify the entity you are working on

Comment: @GuidoPreite Am Working on lead Entity

Answer (score 0):

The "Send Direct Email" page url is like:

```
http://XXXX:5555/OrgName/_grid/cmds/dlg_bulkemail.aspx?bulkemail=true&multiPage=false&objectTypeCode=8
```